# Databricks Workflow - Install dependent librairies from a requirements.txt and not one by one

Tags: python, task, databricks, workflow

I'm using Workflows in Databricks to automate some of my old python scripts (**py files and not Notebook**)

I always use a requirements.txt where I list all the librairies needed for my virtual environment. Now to replicate this, I have to add every single librairies in my requirements.txt one by one (see pictures below)

[Define my task using a Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T7sN.png)
[Add dependent library via PyPi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozc8B.png)

Is there a better way to do this ? I don't see my self do this for every script I'm going to deploy with databricks.

Thank you for the support,
S

Comment: I am facing the same problem and totally agree with you. Did you find a solution? A possibility is to use machines from a pool, and ensure those machines install something in an init script that searches for the correct requirements file depending on something for each workflow. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

One way forward is to functionalise and package your code and then install that custom Python library in the notebook (by calling `%pip install myPythonLibrary`).